# Are elasticsearch documents logged in original format before being indexed?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to apply mappings, transformation etc on elasticsearch documents on their original format (meaning, in the format as they would be send by logstash, curl or any other client).

Afaik, the documents being already indexed in ES are enriched by some metadata (_id, _source, ..), conversions etc.

Does elasticsearch log the documents in their original format without any modifications being applied somewhere? Something like a inbuild raw http log would be already sufficient.

Comment: how do you send your documents to ES?

Comment: I'm using an apache spark-ES connector (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html) within a Java application

Comment: Then why not use `saveAsTextFile` in parallel to `saveToEs`?

Comment: Am using Spark Structured Streaming (writeStream().outputMode("append").
.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")) , there is no saveAsTextFile method. Also I don't think that the original document json would be saved by the client (spark) side without modifications like it would enter ES. Was looking for a inbuild solution on ES-side. If there is no such possibility, I fear I've to use a http-proxy or similar in between to get the original format